# How to block special characters in HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I just want ask if how I will block special characters such as <,>,",/,etc. in html input field?

Comment: By "block" do you mean not allowed to be typed in? What about pasting text?

Comment: For what purpose? Are you trying to prevent the user from using HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex.

```js
document.getElementById("input").onkeypress = function(e) {
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(this.value) // return true or false
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: It is not *blocking*. `pattern` is for validation only

Answer (score 7):

Why not use html5?

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+">
```

Comment: This way must to use in a form.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly state which characters you accept [HTML input pattern Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

If you insist on blocking specific characters you can use the following:

```js
document.getElementById("explicit-block-txt").onkeypress = function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ("></\"".indexOf(chr) >= 0)
        return false;
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='explicit-block-txt' value='' onpaste="return false"/>
```